# Cannot get data into a material ui collapsible table with react. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Code runs and I get the table but I'm also retreiving some database data.  I threw a couple console.logs in the there and my query runs and returns data.  However, it doesn't show up in the collapsible table.  Appreciate any advice!

```
  import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

  import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
  import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
  import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
  import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
  import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
  import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
  import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
  import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
  import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
  import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
  import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
  import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
  import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown';
  import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp';

  import CreateTicket from "views/Dashboard/CreateTicket";
  import {
    LIST_CREATIVE_FORM,
    SUBMIT_CREATIVE_FORM,
    COMPLETE_CREATIVE_FORM
  } from "queries/formSubmission";
  import { READ_ME } from "queries/users";
  import { Context } from "redux/store";

  export default function Tickets() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
    const [selectedCreative, setSelectedCreative] = useState(null);
    const customer_id = state.customers?.selected?.id;
    const { data: me } = useQuery(READ_ME);
    let { loading, data, refetch } = useQuery(LIST_CREATIVE_FORM, {
      skip: !customer_id,
      variables: { customerId: customer_id }
    });

    const [completeCreativeForm, { loading: completing }] = useMutation(COMPLETE_CREATIVE_FORM, {
      skip: !customer_id,
      onCompleted: () => {
        refetch();
      }
    });

    data = data?.listCreativeForm || [];
    console.log(data);
    const editable = me?.readMe?.user_level === "master" || me?.readMe?.user_level === "master";
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Creative or Promotion Name",
        accessor: "creative_promotion_name"
      },
      {
        Header: "Creative Messaging",
        accessor: "creative_message"
      },
      {
        Header: "Start Date",
        accessor: "creative_start"
      },
      {
        Header: "End Date",
        accessor: "creative_end"
      },
      {
        Header: "Landing Page",
        accessor: "landing_page"
      },
      {
        Header: "Notes",
        accessor: "notes"
      },
      {
        Header: "BanerAds",
        accessor: "bannerads",
        Cell: ({ original }) => original?.bannerads ? "Yes" : "No"
      },
      {
        Header: "SocialAds",
        accessor: "socialads",
        Cell: ({ original }) => original?.socialads ? "Yes" : "No"
      },
      {
        Header: "OnlineVideo",
        accessor: "onlinevideo",
        Cell: ({ original }) => original?.onlinevideo ? "Yes" : "No"
      },
      {
        Header: "Out of Home",
        accessor: "out_of_home",
        Cell: ({ original }) => original?.out_of_home ? "Yes" : "No"
      },
      {
        Header: "Link to Asset",
        accessor: "link_to_assets",
        Cell: ({ original }) => (
          <a href={original?.link_to_assets} target="_blank">
            {original?.link_to_assets ? "View" : ""}
          </a>
        )
      },
      {
        Header: "Submitted By",
        accessor: "submitted_by",
        Cell: ({ original }) => (
          <div>{original?.user_submitted ? `${original.user_submitted?.first_name} ${original.user_submitted?.last_name}` : ""}</div>
        )
      },
      {
        Header: "Completed",
        accessor: "completed",
        Cell: ({ original }) => original?.completed
          ? <div style={{ color: "green" }}>Yes</div>
          : <div style={{ color: "red" }}>No</div>
      },
      {
        Header: "Completed By",
        accessor: "completed_by",
        Cell: ({ original }) => (
          <>
            <div>{original?.user_completed ? `${original.user_completed?.first_name} ${original.user_completed?.last_name}` : ""}</div>
            {editable && !original?.completed && (
              <a
                href="#"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  completeCreativeForm({
                    variables: {
                      id: original?.id
                    }
                  });
                }}
              >
                Complete
              </a>
            )}
          </>
        )
      },
      {
        Header: "",
        accessor: "update",
        Cell: ({ original }) => (
          editable && !original?.completed && (
            <a
              href="#"
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setSelectedCreative(original);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </a>
          )
        )
      }
    ];

  Tickets.propTypes = {
    offline: PropTypes.bool
  };

  const useRowStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      '& > *': {
        borderBottom: 'unset',
      },
    },
  });

  function Row(props) {
    const { row } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useRowStyles();
    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TableRow className={classes.root} columns={columns} data={data}>
          <TableCell>
            <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
              {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{data.values.creative_promotion_name} lhey</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{data.values.creative_message}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{data.values.creative_start}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{data.values.creative_end}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <Box margin={1}>
                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                  History
                </Typography>
                <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Total price ($)</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  {/*<TableBody>
                    {row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                      <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                          {historyRow.date}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{historyRow.customerId}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.amount}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">
                          {Math.round(historyRow.amount * row.price * 100) / 100}
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                    </TableBody>*/}
                </Table>
              </Box>
            </Collapse>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  console.log(columns)

    return (
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table aria-label="collapsible table" columns={columns} data={data}>
          <TableBody>
            {data.map((row) => (
              <Row key={row.id} row={row} />
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's what code worked for me to pass my database data to the collapsible table...

```
   function Row(props) {
      const { row } = props;
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
      const classes = useRowStyles();

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
              </IconButton>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.creative_promotion_name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.creative_message}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.creative_start}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.creative_end}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.out_of_home}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.link_to_assets}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.submitted_by}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.completed}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.completed_by}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.update}</TableCell>              
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={4}>
              <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <Box margin={1}>
                  <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Notes:</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left">{row.notes}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>Created Time:</TableCell>
                          <TableCell align="left">{row.created_time}
                          </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                  </Table>
                </Box>
              </Collapse>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }

    const classes = useRowStyles();

    return (
      <div>
        <TableContainer component={Paper} style={{overflowY: "auto", maxWidth: "100%", maxHeight: "600px"}}>
          <h2 className={classes.pageHeader}>Tickets</h2>
          <Table stickyHeader  aria-label="collapsible table" columns={columns} data={data}>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
              <TableCell />
                {columns.map((data) => (
                  <TableCell>{data.Header}</TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {data.map((datarow) => (
                <Row data={datarow.id} row={datarow} />
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
      );
    }
```